# Hide the feed in My profile - Community Page

Tags: profile, customer-community

In the OOB page (My Profile), I need to remove the feed inside the "User profile" component to keep just with the first section of the below image. Since both of them are parte of the same component I am not able to hide it. Does someone knows how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to edit the OOTB Userprofile component. As the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_user_profile.htm&type=5) suggests,

> If you prefer, you can create a custom layout with more granular control over the placement of user profile content.
> Create a custom site page, and use the profile components to build
> your own version of a profile. Profile components include the User
> Profile Summary, User Profile Tabs, User Profile Statistics, User
> Profile Knows About, and User Profile Related List components.